# Reverse for 'quiz_change' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['suppliers/quiz/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path

from .views import classroom, suppliers, teachers
urlpatterns = [
    path('', classroom.home, name='home'),

    path('suppliers/', include(([
        path('', suppliers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='quiz_list'),
        path('interests/', suppliers.SupplierTruckView.as_view(), name='supplier_trucks'),
        path('taken/', suppliers.TakenQuizListView.as_view(), name='taken_quiz_list'),
        path('quiz/<int:pk>/', suppliers.take_quiz, name='take_quiz'),
        path('quiz/edit/<int:pk>/', suppliers.edit_quiz, name='edit_quiz'),

        # teachers modules
        path('quiz/add/', suppliers.QuizCreateView.as_view(), name='quiz_add'),
        path('quiz/confirm/<int:pk>/', suppliers.QuizUpdateView.as_view(), name='quiz_change'),

        path('quiz/<int:pk>/delete/', suppliers.QuizDeleteView.as_view(),name='quiz_delete'),

        path('quiz/<int:pk>/question/add/', suppliers.question_add, name='question_add'),
        path('quiz/<int:quiz_pk>/question/<int:question_pk>/', suppliers.question_change, name='question_change'),

        path('myposts', suppliers.QuizListView1.as_view(), name='quiz_change_list'),
        path('quiz/<int:pk>/results/', suppliers.QuizResultsView.as_view(), name='truck_results'),


    ], 'classroom'), namespace='suppliers')),
```

views.py

```
class QuizUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Activetruck
    fields = ('name', 'subject', 'origin', 'destination','total_trucks','scheduled_date','offered_price',)
    context_object_name = 'quiz'
    template_name = 'classroom/suppliers/quiz_change_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['questions'] = self.get_object().questions1.annotate(answers_count=Count('answers1'))
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.activetruck.all()

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('suppliers:quiz_change', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

when my django app try to access the undermentioned URL:

```
 path('quiz/confirm/<int:pk>/', suppliers.QuizUpdateView.as_view(), name='quiz_change'),
```

it shows NoReverseMatch error. I am unable to figure out where this is coming from. Should I add the traceback too ?

This is the template in QuizUpdateView:

```
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'suppliers:quiz_change_list' %}">My Quizzes</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'suppliers:quiz_change' activetruck.pk %}">{{ quiz.name }}</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Results</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
  <h2 class="mb-3">{{ quiz.name }} Results</h2>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <strong>Posted Requests For Quotes</strong>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary float-right">Least Bid: {{ quiz_score.least_bid|default_if_none:0.0 }}</span>
    </div>
    <table class="table mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>supplier</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Bid Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for taken_quiz in taken_quizzes %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ taken_quiz.supplier.user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ taken_quiz.date|naturaltime }}</td>
            <td>{{ taken_quiz.least_bid }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
      Total respondents: <strong>{{ total_taken_quizzes }}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I suppose the error is in the template file as I have already checked the code  thoroughly

Traceback :

> Template error: In template
>   C:\Users\Sid\Downloads\aggregator-master\django_school\templates\base.html,
>   error at line 0    Reverse for 'quiz_change' with arguments '('',)'
>   not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['suppliers/quiz/confirm/(?P[0-9]+)/$']    1 : {% load static
>   %}    2 :     3 :       4 :
>       5 :         6
>   :     {% block title %}Yantraksh Freight{% endblock %} 
>   7 :         8 :
>       9 :         10 :
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     156.                 response = response.render()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in render
>     106.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py"
>   in render
>     61.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     175.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in _render
>     167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in _render
>     167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py"
>   in reverse
>     88.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py"
>   in _reverse_with_prefix
>     632.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /suppliers/quiz/1/results/ Exception
>   Value: Reverse for 'quiz_change' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['suppliers/quiz/confirm/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: Please show the template for the view that is giving the error.

Comment: update the question, Please check now

Comment: That template doesn't refer to the quiz_change URL. Please show the full traceback so we can see where the error is actually coming from.

Comment: Can you please search your templates and find the one that actually is doing `{% url 'quiz_change' ... %}`. So far you haven't posted it so we can't help you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is this fine ? Please check now

Comment: @DanielRoseman this template is in QuizResultsView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have anything called `activetruck` in that view. Your context object name is `quiz`, which you already use on the same line; you need to be consistent.

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'suppliers:quiz_change' quiz.pk %}">{{ quiz.name }}</a></li>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'suppliers:quiz_change' quiz.id %}">{{ quiz.name }}</a></li>
```

Just change `quiz.pk` to `quiz.id`.